# quiver3 gives non-conformant arguments?

Tags: visualization, octave, vectorization

Does anyone know why I'm seeing these errors? I'm not giving it a matrix.

```
>>> t = 0:0.1:2*pi;
>>> quiver3(4*t,3*cos(t),3*sin(t));
error: __quiver__: operator +: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 3969x1, op2 is 6
3x1)
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/plot/private/__quiver__.m at line 179, colum
n 10
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/plot/quiver3.m at line 75, column 11
```

Comment: You're not even saying what programming language/math system this is. A bit more context would help!

Answer (score 1):

Matlab is a bit more explicit than Octave:

> quiver3(4*t,3*cos(t),3*sin(t))
>
> ??? Error using ==> quiver3 at 53
>
> Not enough input arguments.

There is no way of using `quiver3` with only 3 arguments. What did you want to do?

Comment: Ohhh I see what Im doing wrong, I have to include the derivatives for them. quiver3(4*t,3*cos(t),3*sin(t),4,-3*sin(t),3*cos(t));